# How can I fix an element to the page that is of a variable distance from the edge of the screen?

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I have a graphic that I need to appear as a sticky element 66% of the way across the container div of my webpage. 'position:fixed' would normally be exactly what I want, however, since this fixes to the viewport and the container div is sometimes an unknown distance from the edge of the viewport, I can't use it to determine the precise horizontal point at which it should display.

Some more info: The container div is responsive and a maximum of 1080px, centered in the viewport when the viewport is wider than 1080px. So the position of this graphic can be determined with reference to the viewport only up to 1080px wide. Beyond that point, the graphic needs to appear at [(total-width-of-viewport-1080px)/2 + 66% of 1080px]. No idea how to render that with CSS!

Another approach that occurred to me is to use absolute positioning to fix the element precisely to the container div and use some jquery magic to update the vertical position with regards to the viewport top as the user scrolls to give it a 'sticky' quality. However, all solutions I've found for this approach seem like massive overkill for what I want to achieve.

I'd be really grateful for any solutions or advice.

Edit: I've attached an image to illustrate the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX9xw.png

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words... in this case a picture or fiddle. A link to a live site doesn't help and will soo be obsolete, so your question and its answers could be unusable to future SO users.

Comment: Use jquery to find that element's position and then use of the functions like `append()`, `insertBefore()` etc.

Comment: The thing you need to do is wrap your elements in a `<div>` and give it `position: relative;` so the elements become 'grouped'

Comment: You could try `calc((100vw-1080px)/2 + (1080px * 2/3))`.  Both [calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) and [vw](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) have decent support, even for IE.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I've added an image to illustrate the problem which I hope makes things clearer. DSMann8 - is calc() a CSS thing? I guess I could just google that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DSMann8 alerting me to the existence of both calc() and VW and a little bit of googling, I've solved the problem. Here is the full CSS for the element I was trying to position, for anyone interested:

```
span#scissors {
  background: transparent url(../imgs/new/scissors.png) no-repeat left top;
  display: block;       
  width: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  position: fixed;  
  top: 400px;
}

@media (max-width: 1080px) {
  span#scissors {
    left: calc(66VW - 8px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1079px) {
  span#scissors {
    left: calc(((100VW - 1080px) / 2) + (1080px * 2/3));
    margin-left: -8px;
  }
}
```

Thank you all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Give the outer `div` a `position:relative` and the inner one a `position:absolute`.

Run the snippet in full screen and play with window size. you can also change window size in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/2u50do6j/1/)

```css
#wrapper{
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: goldenrod;
    height: 300px;
}

#elem {
    width: 66%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: royalblue;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="elem">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to do this, but I don't need the element absolutely positioned. I need it to be "sticky" - outside the flow of the page so that it remains in the same place with regards to the viewport at all times. However, using "position: fixed" means I can't accurately locate it's horizontal position because of the structure of the page. is that any clearer?